# GuzzleHttp\Client 400 bad request on Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I am sending a POST request to an API, Curl returns 200 and the correct response.
When Implementing with GuzzleHttp\Client, I get a 400 Bad request, what is wrong with my formatting.

here is my code using Laravel Returns 400 Bad Request:

```
 $client = new Client();

$URI = 'http://api.example.com';
$params['headers'] = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'apikey' => config('app._api_key'),
    'debug' => true
];
$params['form_params'] = [
    'sender' => 'Test_sender',
    'recipient' => config('app.test_recipient'),
    'message_body' => 'Test  body'
];
return $response = $client->post($URI, $params);
```

Curl (Returns 200):

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'apikey: 212121212’ -d '{ "message_body": "test","sender": "2018","recipient": “4453424141” }' 'http://api.example.com'
```

Comment: Did you try changing ‘form_params’ to ‘json’? Your headers claim the request is a JSON request but you are sending unencoded data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                                                'apikey'=> config('app._api_key'),
                                                'debug' => true
                                                ]
                                ]);
$URI = 'http://api.example.com';
$body['sender']='Test_sender';
$body['recipient']=config('app.test_recipient');
$body['message_body']='Test  body';
$body=json_encode($body);
$URI_Response = $client->request('POST',$URI,['body'=>$body]);
$URI_Response =json_decode($URI_Response->getBody(), true);
return $URI_Response;
```

Note: I would suggest you to handle error please refer [GuzzleDocumentation](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

That is proper error handling:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

try {

    $response = $client->get(YOUR_URL, [
        'connect_timeout' => 10
    ]);

    // Here the code for successful request

} catch (RequestException $e) {

    // Catch all 4XX errors 

    // To catch exactly error 400 use 
    if ($e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '400') {
            echo "Got response 400";
    }

    // You can check for whatever error status code you need 

} catch (\Exception $e) {

    // There was another exception.

}
```

Implementation: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: ok, I implemented that before how do I get the specific error? echoing 400 is not helping.

Comment: echo $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode()

Comment: Apparently I am on Laravel 5.4, I get Call to a member function getStatusCode() on null

Comment: ok .env vars were not in place , now just getting 400, no details

Comment: A 400 means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules.

Comment: I need to pass the apikey in the headers and params in the body, is the above guzzle request correct? I get no feedback what is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle errors like this

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use Exception;


try{
    $client = new Client();

    $response = $client->request('POST', $url,[
         'headers' => $header,
         'form_params' => $form-params
    ]);
    $body = $response->getBody();
    $status = 'true';
    $message = 'Data found!';
    $data = json_decode($body);
}catch(ClientException $ce){
    $status = 'false';
    $message = $ce->getMessage();
    $data = [];
}catch(RequestException $re){
   $status = 'false';
   $message = $re->getMessage();
   $data = [];
}catch(Exception $e){
   $this->status = 'false';
   $this->message = $e->getMessage();
   $data = [];
}

return ['status'=>$status,'message'=>$message,'data'=>$data];
```